# "Error reading package header" when using the Ansible yum install module

Tags: yaml, ansible

I have an ansible script that looks like this, and it was working properly yesterday -

```
- name: Dockerfile
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
     - name: Install repositories packages
       yum:
         name: "{{ item }}"
         state: present
       with_items:
         - https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
         - http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.7/3.7.10/CentOS/glusterfs-epel.repo
```

However this morning when I ran it, I got the following error -

```
failed: [localhost] (item=[u'https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm', u'http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.7/3.7.10/CentOS/glusterfs-epel.repo']) => {"failed": true, "invocation": {"module_name": "yum"}, "item": ["https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm", "http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.7/3.7.10/CentOS/glusterfs-epel.repo"], "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_mdVzzz/ansible_module_yum.py\", line 1064, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_mdVzzz/ansible_module_yum.py\", line 1053, in main\n    disablerepo, disable_gpg_check, exclude, repoquery)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_mdVzzz/ansible_module_yum.py\", line 969, in ensure\n    res = install(module, pkgs, repoq, yum_basecmd, conf_file, en_repos, dis_repos)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_mdVzzz/ansible_module_yum.py\", line 595, in install\n    pkg_name = local_name(module, package)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_mdVzzz/ansible_module_yum.py\", line 492, in local_name\n    header = ts.hdrFromFdno(fd)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpm/transaction.py\", line 160, in hdrFromFdno\n    raise rpm.error(\"error reading package header\")\n_rpm.error: error reading package header\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

The actual error description is

```
raise rpm.error(\"error reading package header\")\n_rpm.error: error reading package header\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

Did I break something?  Or is this more of an issue with the gluster RPM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this one:

```
     - name: Install repositories packages
       yum:
         name: "{{ item }}"
         state: present
       with_items:
         - https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm

     - name: Install the gluster repo
       get_url:
         url: "http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.7/3.7.10/CentOS/glusterfs-epel.repo" 
         dest: "/etc/yum.repos.d/glusterfs-epel.repo"
         mode: 0644
```

Comment: That worked.  I had to remove the empty `baseurl` parameter, but otherwise it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: I was testing something and forgot to remove that, I have updated the answer.